# Алгоритм сохранения уже загруженых изображений в БД

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Собственно такой простой вопрос возник. Есть форма с несколькими полями, которая добавляет обьявления в БД. В форме есть ajax [загрузка изображений](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input-ajax-demo/4), и у меня возникает вопрос как передавать уже загруженные картинки при отправке самой формы. Самое первое что приходить в голову, так это создать скрытое поле и туда помещать название картинок, при успешном ajax запросе.

Comment: можете использовать localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Я бы делал так. При открытии формы, создается пустая запись в БД получаем ее идентификатор. После сабмита формы используем этот id для того чтобы прикрепить картинки к записи.

Comment: Но есть момент, начинаешь добавлять новую запись, загрузил картинки и потом закрыл страницу и создалась пустая запись с картинкой. Забыл еще уточнить изображений много может быть. (макс 7)

Comment: Я бы добавил поле "show", которое по умолчанию false, true надо включать вручную в админке